# Не работают псевдоселекторы first-child и nth-child

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

```css
.features {
  width: 695px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.f1 {
  float: left;
}

.f2 {}

.f3 {
  float: right;
}

.features p:first-child {
  color: #22795b;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">

  <div class="f1">
    <center>
      <img src="img/1.png" alt="Фиксированные цены">
      <p>Фиксированные цены</p>
    </center>
  </div>

  <center>
    <div class="f2">
      <center>
        <img src="img/2.png" alt="Определенные сроки">
        <p>определенные сроки</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>

  <center>
    <div class="f3">
      <center>
        <img src="img/3.png" alt="Гарантированная сатисфакция">
        <p>гарантированная сатисфакция</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Пример должен быть минимальным.

Comment: Исправил, надеюсь, теперь лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`:first-child`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-child) это псевдокласс.
Как будто кто-то прошелся по вашему коду и добавил в каждый первый дочерний элемент родительского элемента класс `first-child`.

```
<body>
  <div class="features first-child">  <!-- Сюда добавил - div.features первый в body -->
    <div class="f1 first-child">      <!-- Сюда добавил - div.f1 первый в div.features -->
      <center class="first-child">    <!-- Сюда добавил - center первый в div.f1 -->
        <img>                         <!-- Сюда добавил - img первый в center -->
        <p></p>                       <!-- А сюда не добавил - p не первый элемент в center -->
      </center>
    </div>
    <div class="f2">                  <!-- И сюда не добавил - div.f2 не первый элемент в div.features -->
  </div>
</body>
```

То есть правило

```
.features p:first-child { color: #22795b; }
```

сработает для элемента только если:

- элемент первый дочерний элемент (имеет класс `:first-child`)
- элемент `p`
- элемент является дочерним для `.features` на любом уровне вложенности

---

Другое дело псевдокласс [`:first-of-type`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-of-type), 
который применяется к первому дочернему элементу по типу элемента.

```css
div :first-of-type {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Это span первый!</span>
  <span>Это span нет. :(</span>
  <span>что насчёт этого <em>вложенного элемента</em>?</span>
  <strike>Это другой тег</strike>
  <span>Грустно, это тоже нет...</span>
</div>
```

<sub>Пример взят с сайта *MDN*. [Ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)</sub>

---

В вашем примере нужно заменить `.features p:first-child` на `.features p:first-of-type`, чтобы заработало так, как вы ожидаете.

```css
.features {
  width: 695px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.f1 {
  float: left;
}

.f2 {}

.f3 {
  float: right;
}

.features p:first-of-type {
  color: #22795b;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">

  <div class="f1">
    <center>
      <img src="img/1.png" alt="Фиксированные цены">
      <p>Фиксированные цены</p>
    </center>
  </div>

  <center>
    <div class="f2">
      <center>
        <img src="img/2.png" alt="Определенные сроки">
        <p>определенные сроки</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>

  <center>
    <div class="f3">
      <center>
        <img src="img/3.png" alt="Гарантированная сатисфакция">
        <p>гарантированная сатисфакция</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Селектор необходимо применять к первым вложенным элементам в родитель. Учитывая разную разметку в примере я бы привязался вот так:

```css
.features {
  width: 695px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.f1 {
  float: left;
}

.f2 {}

.f3 {
  float: right;
}

.features > *:first-child p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">

  <div class="f1">
    <center>
      <img src="img/1.png" alt="Фиксированные цены">
      <p>Фиксированные цены</p>
    </center>
  </div>

  <center>
    <div class="f2">
      <center>
        <img src="img/2.png" alt="Определенные сроки">
        <p>определенные сроки</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>

  <center>
    <div class="f3">
      <center>
        <img src="img/3.png" alt="Гарантированная сатисфакция">
        <p>гарантированная сатисфакция</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```