# Сделать жирным определённый текст в <ul><li> посредством css :first-child

Tags: css3, html5, ul

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли какой-нибудь универсальный метод, как задать :first-child именно для определённого элемента автоматически. Может есть что-то более удобное, нежели написывать каждый раз  или  с классом, дабы обособить жирнотой только определённый текст?

```css
#aloha:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <ul id="aloha">
    <li>1923 - ДЕВАСТАЦИЯ УМЕРЕННЫХ ВЕЛИЧИН
      <li>1933 - КОГЕРЕТНАЯ ОБЛАСТЬ ПРОЕКТИРОВАНИЯ
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/696884/262779

Answer (score 1):

Просто надо добавить li перед :first-child

```css
#aloha li:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul id="aloha">
    <li>1923 - ДЕВАСТАЦИЯ УМЕРЕННЫХ ВЕЛИЧИН
      <li>1933 - КОГЕРЕТНАЯ ОБЛАСТЬ ПРОЕКТИРОВАНИЯ
  </ul>
```

:first-child, :last-child и т.д. - это псевдоклассы, их надо применять к самим дочерним элементам, а не к родительским

Comment: Альтернатива `#aloha li:nth-child(1)`